# Wiki-like table sorting for electron-based app

Tags: html, typescript, dom

I am writing a plugin for [Obsidian](https://obsidian.md/) (using their [API](https://github.com/obsidianmd/obsidian-api)), hoping to achieve [wiki-like table sorting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Sorting#Example), i.e. clickable headers that can sort the table in ascending (1st click), then descending (2nd click), then finally restoring the original order (3rd click).

I wrote the following code that registers a click DOM event with a callback that checks whether the click was performed inside a table and if so, it sorts the table, essentially by reordering `tr` elements. However, I am not sure how to *restore* the table to the original state on the third click.

```js
this.registerDomEvent(document, 'click', (evt: MouseEvent) => {
    const htmlEl = (<HTMLInputElement>evt.target);

    const th = htmlEl.closest('thead th');
    if (th == null) { return; }

    const table = htmlEl.closest('table');
    const tbody = table.querySelector('tbody');
    const thArray = Array.from(th.parentNode.children);
    const thIdx = thArray.indexOf(th);

    // all other th's are reset
    thArray.forEach((th, i) => {
        if (i != thIdx) {
            th.removeAttribute("class");
        }
    });

    // set clicked th class
    th.className = this.classNames[
        (this.classNames.indexOf(th.className) + 1) % this.classNames.length
    ];

    const ascending = th.className === "header-sort-up";

    Array.from(tbody.querySelectorAll('tr:nth-child(n)'))
        .sort(this.compareFn(thIdx, ascending))
        .forEach(tr => tbody.appendChild(tr));
});
```

One idea I had was to make use of the `localStorage` to store the original `innerHTML` of the table, but I think this will not scale well for persistent, long-term usage, and lots of tables. Moreover, I don't want to add extra dependencies, if possible.

Comment: Could you update your question with the relevant code (a [minimal, working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example))?

Comment: Do you only have access to the html table or would it be an option to sort the data in JavaScript and then generate the table from there?

Comment: @Emaro - I have immediate access to the HTML table. My first solution, as I mentioned, was to reorder `tr` elements. However, I can construct a JavaScript object with the data in the table, then generate the HTML for the sorted table, but I still don't see how to restore the original order.

Comment: I don't know the structure of you tr's, but maybe you can derive an id and only store the original order of the ids.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this problem, I'm going to assume that the table will have a `<thead>` (for the clickable elements) and a single `<tbody>`.

## Native JS API for interacting with `<table>`

A good thing to know is that a `<table>` element in JS has a special interface [HTMLTableElement](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement) that allows us to perform a few selections / actions easily. So once we select our element:

```js
const table = document.querySelector('table')
```

We have access to its entire structure. For example:

- `table.tHead` returns the `<thead>`
- `table.tBodies[0]` returns the `<tbody>`
- `table.tBodies[0].deleteRow(-1)` removes the last `<tr>` from the body
- `table.tBodies[0].rows[0].cells[0].cellIndex` returns the index of the first cell (`th` or `td`) in the first row (`tr`) of the `tbody`
- ...

## Defining a component state

Also, because of the behavior you describe, we know we're going to need to store a few "state" variables:

- `initialList` the initial order of rows

  This one is easy with the [HTMLTableSectionElement](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableSectionElement) interface `.rows`, stored into an array, and we're never touching it again

  ```js
  Array.from(tBody.rows)
  ```
- `currentOrder` the current order in which to sort the rows (either the initial, ascending, or descending order)

  For this, I'm going to simply use either `0`, `1`, or `2` based on the three possible orders. Which makes it easy to iterate over: we just need to run the following line on every order change:

  ```js
  currentOrder = (currentOrder + 1) % 3
  ```
- `currentSortReference` the current column that we want to use to sort the rows

  For this one, I'll go with storing the index of the column used for sorting. To get that value, we just need to know the index of the `<tr>` clicked in `<thead>`. This is made easy by the [HTMLTableCellElement](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableCellElement) interface `cellIndex`:

  ```js
  const index = currentTarget.cellIndex
  ```

## Basic utility functions

For a problem like this, I like to start by writing a few simple utility functions. They are nothing complicated, just using standard JS (and again, native HTMLTableElement interfaces). Here we will need

- `emptyTable` to empty the table body

  ```js
  function emptyTable(tBody, rows) {
      rows.forEach(() => tBody.deleteRow(-1))
  }
  ```
- `fillTable` to fill the table body with ordered rows

  ```js
  function fillTable(tBody, rows) {
      rows.forEach((row) => tBody.appendChild(row))
  }
  ```
- `valueFromCell` to parse a value from the text in a cell

  ```js
  function valueFromCell(element) {
      return Number(element.textContent)
  }
  ```
- `compareRows` to compare the values of 2 rows (based on the values in a specific column). This is meant to be the compare function of an `Array.sort()` which is why it returns these values

  ```js
  function compareRows(a, b, index) {
      const valueA = valueFromCell(a.cells[index])
      const valueB = valueFromCell(b.cells[index])
      return valueA >= valueB
          ? 1
          : -1
  }
  ```

## Component logic

Now that we have all these pieces, it's just a matter of putting them together:

1. onclick event `onHeadClick`

   - get the column that was clicked (this is `event.currentTarget.cellIndex` like mentioned above)
   - if it's the same that was clicked before (`currentSortReference`), just iterate the order (`currentOrder`)
   - if it's not, reset the order
   - sort the table based on the current state (see below)

   ```js
   function onHeadClick({currentTarget}) {
       const index = currentTarget.cellIndex
       if (currentSortReference === index) {
           currentOrder = (currentOrder + 1) % 3
       } else {
           currentSortReference = index
           currentOrder = 1
       }
       sortTable(currentSortReference, currentOrder, tBody, initialList)
   }
   ```
2. sort the table `sortTable`

   - empty the table with `emptyTable`
   - if it's the initial order, just fill the table (`fillTable`) with `initialList`
   - if it's not, create a new array from `initialList` and sort it with the native `Array.sort` and the simple function we defined before `compareRows`, and then fill the table (`fillTable`).

   ```js
   function sortTable(sort, order, tBody, rows) {
       emptyTable(tBody, rows)
       if (order === 0) {
           fillTable(tBody, rows)
       } else {
           const newList = [...rows]
           newList.sort((a, b) => compareRows(a, b, sort))
           if(order === 2) {
               newList.reverse()
           }
           fillTable(tBody, newList)
       }
   }
   ```

## Solution

That's it! It's quite a bit of code, but once you take it bit by bit, it's all fairly straightforward.

```js
const table = document.querySelector('table')
const heads = table.tHead.rows[0].cells
const tBody = table.tBodies[0]

let currentSortReference = null
let currentOrder = 0
const initialList = Array.from(tBody.rows)

Array.from(heads).forEach(th => {
    th.addEventListener('click', onHeadClick)
})

/**
 * @param {MouseEvent} event
 */
function onHeadClick({currentTarget}) {
    const index = currentTarget.cellIndex
    if (currentSortReference === index) {
        currentOrder = (currentOrder + 1) % 3
    } else {
        currentSortReference = index
        currentOrder = 1
    }
    sortTable(currentSortReference, currentOrder, tBody, initialList)
}

/**
 * @param {Number} sort index of head to base sort on
 * @param {0 | 1 | 2} order 0: initial, 1: descending, 2: ascending
 * @param {HTMLTableSectionElement} tBody 
 * @param {HTMLTableRowElement[]} rows all rows, in initial order
 */
function sortTable(sort, order, tBody, rows) {
    emptyTable(tBody, rows)
    if (order === 0) {
        fillTable(tBody, rows)
    } else {
        const newList = [...rows]
        newList.sort((a, b) => compareRows(a, b, sort))
        if(order === 2) {
            newList.reverse()
        }
        fillTable(tBody, newList)
    }
}


/**
 * @param {HTMLTableRowElement} a 
 * @param {HTMLTableRowElement} b 
 * @param {Number} index of column to use in comparison
 */
function compareRows(a, b, index) {
    const valueA = valueFromCell(a.cells[index])
    const valueB = valueFromCell(b.cells[index])
    return valueA >= valueB
        ? 1
        : -1
}

/**
 * @param {HTMLTableCellElement} element 
 */
function valueFromCell(element) {
    return Number(element.textContent)
}

/**
 * @param {HTMLTableSectionElement} tBody 
 * @param {HTMLTableRowElement[]} rows
 */
function emptyTable(tBody, rows) {
    rows.forEach(() => tBody.deleteRow(-1))
}

/**
 * @param {HTMLTableSectionElement} tBody 
 * @param {HTMLTableRowElement[]} rows
 */
function fillTable(tBody, rows) {
    rows.forEach((row) => tBody.appendChild(row))
}
```

```html
<table>
    <caption>Council budget (in £) 2018</caption>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">Items</th>
            <th scope="col">Expenditure</th>
            <th scope="col">Qty</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">Donuts</th>
            <td>3000</td>
            <td>42</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">Stationery</th>
            <td>18000</td>
            <td>3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">Chairs</th>
            <td>100</td>
            <td>248</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the comprehensive and clear explanation! Regarding `initialList`, I assume it's ok to store it into `localStorage`? In this case, wouldn't there be a problem with a large number of tables? Or if someone tampers with `localStorage` somehow?

Comment: `initialList` is an array of DOM nodes, and `localStorage` only accepts strings, so storing it in localStorage wouldn't work. But you could write a pair of method to do `arrayOfDomNodesToString(initialList)` and `initialList = stringToArrayOfDomNodes()` so that you can put it in and parse it from localStorage.

Comment: I understand. So it's generally ok to use `localStorage` for such purposes. I wonder how Wikipedia does it, though, as it doesn't seem to use `localStorage`?

Comment: No, only use localStorage if you need to persist a state across page loads. In this case, it's probably fine to just keep `initialList` as a variable. You don't need to store it anywhere.

Comment: Ah, right.. that was my confusion! So, in my case, there will be an array of `initialList` which will simply reside in RAM.

Comment: @AlexandruDinu exactly.