# Why can't I get the innerHTML from the 10th cell in a row when it works for cells less than 10?

Tags: javascript, html-table, background-color

Objective:  Show bike riding data and highlight if ride was inside or outside.

Here's the setup that works fine for Sunday and Monday:

```js
var rows = document.getElementsByTagName("tbody")
  [0].getElementsByTagName("tr");

    // loops through each row
    for (i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {cells = rows[i].getElementsByTagName('td');
            if (cells[4].innerHTML == '1')
                cells[3].className = "in",
                cells[2].className = "in";

            if (cells[4].innerHTML == '0')
                cells[3].className = "out",
                cells[2].className = "out"
                
            if (cells[7].innerHTML == '1')
                cells[6].className = "in",
                cells[5].className = "in";

            if (cells[7].innerHTML == '0')
                cells[6].className = "out",
                cells[5].className = "out";

 }
```

```css
table {border-collapse: collapse;}
td {border: 2px solid black;}
.in {
    background-color: red;
}

.out {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<table class="resultGridTable" >
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td colspan="2">Week</td>
         <td colspan="3">Sun (miles/ave)</td>
         <td colspan="3">Mon (miles/ave)</td>
         <td colspan="3">Tue (miles/ave)</td>
         <td colspan="3">Wed (miles/ave)</td>
         <td colspan="3">tdur (miles/ave)</td>
         <td colspan="3">Fri (miles/ave)</td>
         <td colspan="3">Sat (miles/ave)</td>
         <td>Total (miles/ave)</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>39</td>
         <td>2022-09-25</td>
         <td class="sun_miles"></td>
         <td class="sun_ave"></td>
         <td class="sun_out"></td>
         <td class="mon_miles">11.50</td>
         <td class="mon_ave">16.6</td>
         <td class="mon_out">1</td>
         <td class="tue_miles">22</td>
         <td class="tue_ave">19</td>
         <td class="tue_out">1</td>
         <td class="wed_miles"></td>
         <td class="wed_ave"></td>
         <td class="wed_out"></td>
         <td class="thur_miles"></td>
         <td class="thur_ave"></td>
         <td class="thur_out"></td>
         <td class="fri_miles">22.50</td>
         <td class="fri_ave'">17.9</td>
         <td class="fri_out">0</td>
         <td class="sat_miles">20.00</td>
         <td class="sat_ave">17.9</td>
         <td class="sat_out">0</td>
         <td>54.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>38</td>
         <td>2022-09-18</td>
         <td class="sun_miles"></td>
         <td class="sun_ave"></td>
         <td class="sun_out"></td>
         <td class="mon_miles"></td>
         <td class="mon_ave"></td>
         <td class="mon_out"></td>
         <td class="tue_miles">39.00</td>
         <td class="tue_ave">36.1</td>
         <td class="tue_out">0</td>
         <td class="wed_miles">22.00</td>
         <td class="wed_ave">17.8</td>
         <td class="wed_out">0</td>
         <td class="thur_miles">18.00</td>
         <td class="thur_ave">16.8</td>
         <td class="thur_out">0</td>
         <td class="fri_miles"></td>
         <td class="fri_ave'"></td>
         <td class="fri_out"></td>
         <td class="sat_miles">22.00</td>
         <td class="sat_ave">17.7</td>
         <td class="sat_out">0</td>
         <td>101.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>37</td>
         <td>2022-09-11</td>
         <td class="sun_miles">17.00</td>
         <td class="sun_ave">21.8</td>
         <td class="sun_out">1</td>
         <td class="mon_miles">20.00</td>
         <td class="mon_ave">21.3</td>
         <td class="mon_out">1</td>
         <td class="tue_miles">17.00</td>
         <td class="tue_ave">18.6</td>
         <td class="tue_out">0</td>
         <td class="wed_miles">23.00</td>
         <td class="wed_ave">18.4</td>
         <td class="wed_out">0</td>
         <td class="thur_miles">18.00</td>
         <td class="thur_ave">18.8</td>
         <td class="thur_out">0</td>
         <td class="fri_miles">20.00</td>
         <td class="fri_ave'">18.6</td>
         <td class="fri_out">0</td>
         <td class="sat_miles"></td>
         <td class="sat_ave"></td>
         <td class="sat_out"></td>
         <td>115.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>36</td>
         <td>2022-09-04</td>
         <td class="sun_miles">18.00</td>
         <td class="sun_ave">18.8</td>
         <td class="sun_out">0</td>
         <td class="mon_miles"></td>
         <td class="mon_ave"></td>
         <td class="mon_out"></td>
         <td class="tue_miles">19.00</td>
         <td class="tue_ave">18.7</td>
         <td class="tue_out">0</td>
         <td class="wed_miles">23.00</td>
         <td class="wed_ave">18.5</td>
         <td class="wed_out">0</td>
         <td class="thur_miles">17.00</td>
         <td class="thur_ave">18.9</td>
         <td class="thur_out">0</td>
         <td class="fri_miles">17.00</td>
         <td class="fri_ave'">19.0</td>
         <td class="fri_out">0</td>
         <td class="sat_miles">16.00</td>
         <td class="sat_ave">18.9</td>
         <td class="sat_out">0</td>
         <td>110.00</td>
      </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

But when I try to add Tuesday by changing the script to:

```
var rows = document.getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0].getElementsByTagName("tr");

// loops through each row
for (i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {cells = rows[i].getElementsByTagName('td');
        if (cells[4].innerHTML == '1')
            cells[3].className = "in",
            cells[2].className = "in";

        if (cells[4].innerHTML == '0')
            cells[3].className = "out",
            cells[2].className = "out"
            
        if (cells[7].innerHTML == '1')
            cells[6].className = "in",
            cells[5].className = "in";

        if (cells[7].innerHTML == '0')
            cells[6].className = "out",
            cells[5].className = "out";
            
         if (cells[10].innerHTML == '0')
            cells[9].className = "in",
            cells[8].className = "in";

         if  (cells[10].innerHTML == '1')
            cells[9].className = "out",
            cells[8].className = "out";}
```

It does not like that Cell[10] and I get an error message:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'innerHTML')

It doesn't like any number over 10.  I'm lost, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your header row only has 9 `td`s (with colspan so they visually occupy more columns). You need to skip the first row, or skip rows with less than 10 columns, or detect the header row by content and skip it.

Comment: Or, use the standard to your advantage, and put the header row inside a `<thead>` element...

Comment: Suggestion: put all those those if's into a loop (sorry cannot format a comment): for (i=4, i<=22)  {if (cells[i].innerHTML =='1') {....="in;"} if (cells[i].innerHTML=='0') { ... = "out"} } using i-1 and i-2 to set the in's and out's.

Comment: Thanks folks.  Hobbs dump header row fixed it.  Heretic Monkey's <thead> worked after I moved <tbody> to after </thead>.  And TG thanks for the suggestions.  Not there on loops yet but I'll try to make it work.

Comment: Also, for `table`, you don't need to `getElementsByTagName` since there are much better native APIs widely available in all browsers. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67097117/wiki-like-table-sorting-for-electron-based-app/68167948#68167948

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the comments I go it working and hide the in/out column (see code below).  Have not figured out TG's loop yet.

```js
var rows = document.getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0].getElementsByTagName("tr");

    // loops through each row
    for (i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {cells = rows[i].getElementsByTagName('td');
            if (cells[4].innerHTML == '1')
                cells[3].className = "in",
                cells[2].className = "in";

            if (cells[4].innerHTML == '0')
                cells[3].className = "out",
                cells[2].className = "out"
                
            if (cells[7].innerHTML == '1')
                cells[6].className = "in",
                cells[5].className = "in";

            if (cells[7].innerHTML == '0')
                cells[6].className = "out",
                cells[5].className = "out";
                
            if (cells[10].innerHTML == '1')
                cells[9].className = "in",
                cells[8].className = "in";

            if (cells[10].innerHTML == '0')
                cells[9].className = "out",
                cells[8].className = "out";
                
            if (cells[13].innerHTML == '1')
                cells[12].className = "in",
                cells[11].className = "in";

            if (cells[13].innerHTML == '0')
                cells[12].className = "out",
                cells[11].className = "out";                
                
            if (cells[16].innerHTML == '1')
                cells[15].className = "in",
                cells[14].className = "in";

            if (cells[16].innerHTML == '0')
                cells[15].className = "out",
                cells[14].className = "out";
                
            if (cells[19].innerHTML == '1')
                cells[18].className = "in",
                cells[17].className = "in";

            if (cells[19].innerHTML == '0')
                cells[18].className = "out",
                cells[17].className = "out"; 

            if (cells[22].innerHTML == '1')
                cells[21].className = "in",
                cells[20].className = "in";

            if (cells[22].innerHTML == '0')
                cells[21].className = "out",
                cells[20].className = "out";                 
 }
```

```css
table {border-collapse: collapse;}
td {border: 2px solid black;}
.hide {display: none;}
.in {
    background-color: red;
}

.out {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<table class="resultGridTable" >
      <thead>
         <th colspan="2">Week</th>
         <th colspan="3">Sun (miles/ave)</th>
         <th colspan="3">Mon (miles/ave)</th>
         <th colspan="3">Tue (miles/ave)</th>
         <th colspan="3">Wed (miles/ave)</th>
         <th colspan="3">thur (miles/ave)</th>
         <th colspan="3">Fri (miles/ave)</th>
         <th colspan="3">Sat (miles/ave)</th>
         <th>Total (miles/ave)</th>
      </thead>
   <tbody>      
      <tr>
         <td>39</td>
         <td>2022-09-25</td>
         <td class="sun_miles"></td>
         <td class="sun_ave"></td>
         <td class="sun_out hide"></td>
         <td class="mon_miles">11.50</td>
         <td class="mon_ave">16.6</td>
         <td class="mon_out hide">1</td>
         <td class="tue_miles">22</td>
         <td class="tue_ave">19</td>
         <td class="tue_out hide">1</td>
         <td class="wed_miles"></td>
         <td class="wed_ave"></td>
         <td class="wed_out hide"></td>
         <td class="thur_miles"></td>
         <td class="thur_ave"></td>
         <td class="thur_out hide"></td>
         <td class="fri_miles">22.50</td>
         <td class="fri_ave'">17.9</td>
         <td class="fri_out hide">0</td>
         <td class="sat_miles">20.00</td>
         <td class="sat_ave">17.9</td>
         <td class="sat_out hide">0</td>
         <td>54.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>38</td>
         <td>2022-09-18</td>
         <td class="sun_miles"></td>
         <td class="sun_ave"></td>
         <td class="sun_out hide"></td>
         <td class="mon_miles"></td>
         <td class="mon_ave"></td>
         <td class="mon_out hide"></td>
         <td class="tue_miles">39.00</td>
         <td class="tue_ave">36.1</td>
         <td class="tue_out hide">0</td>
         <td class="wed_miles">22.00</td>
         <td class="wed_ave">17.8</td>
         <td class="wed_out hide">0</td>
         <td class="thur_miles">18.00</td>
         <td class="thur_ave">16.8</td>
         <td class="thur_out hide">0</td>
         <td class="fri_miles"></td>
         <td class="fri_ave'"></td>
         <td class="fri_out hide"></td>
         <td class="sat_miles">22.00</td>
         <td class="sat_ave">17.7</td>
         <td class="sat_out hide">0</td>
         <td>101.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>37</td>
         <td>2022-09-11</td>
         <td class="sun_miles">17.00</td>
         <td class="sun_ave">21.8</td>
         <td class="sun_out hide">1</td>
         <td class="mon_miles">20.00</td>
         <td class="mon_ave">21.3</td>
         <td class="mon_out hide">1</td>
         <td class="tue_miles">17.00</td>
         <td class="tue_ave">18.6</td>
         <td class="tue_out hide">0</td>
         <td class="wed_miles">23.00</td>
         <td class="wed_ave">18.4</td>
         <td class="wed_out hide">0</td>
         <td class="thur_miles">18.00</td>
         <td class="thur_ave">18.8</td>
         <td class="thur_out hide">0</td>
         <td class="fri_miles">20.00</td>
         <td class="fri_ave'">18.6</td>
         <td class="fri_out hide">0</td>
         <td class="sat_miles"></td>
         <td class="sat_ave"></td>
         <td class="sat_out hide"></td>
         <td>115.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>36</td>
         <td>2022-09-04</td>
         <td class="sun_miles">18.00</td>
         <td class="sun_ave">18.8</td>
         <td class="sun_out hide">0</td>
         <td class="mon_miles"></td>
         <td class="mon_ave"></td>
         <td class="mon_out hide"></td>
         <td class="tue_miles">19.00</td>
         <td class="tue_ave">18.7</td>
         <td class="tue_out hide">0</td>
         <td class="wed_miles">23.00</td>
         <td class="wed_ave">18.5</td>
         <td class="wed_out hide">0</td>
         <td class="thur_miles">17.00</td>
         <td class="thur_ave">18.9</td>
         <td class="thur_out hide">0</td>
         <td class="fri_miles">17.00</td>
         <td class="fri_ave'">19.0</td>
         <td class="fri_out hide">0</td>
         <td class="sat_miles">16.00</td>
         <td class="sat_ave">18.9</td>
         <td class="sat_out hide">0</td>
         <td>110.00</td>
      </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```